# Reodering list elements using a certain step

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, linked-list

I'm working on the following problem:

> On the round table stands `numberOfDishes` dishes numbered in
> **ascending order** from `1` to `numberOfDishes`. A man wants to try all the dishes according to the following rule:
>
> He will eat every `everyDishNumberToEat` dish until he has eaten
> everything.
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> numberOfDishes = 10
> everyDishNumberToEat = 3
>
> dishes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> [3, 6, 9, 2, 7, 1, 8, 5, 10, 4]
> ```

This is my code where I tried to get each eaten dish number from `LinkedList` and add to my list. Do you have any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

```
public class DishOrderDeterminer {
    public List<Integer> determineDishOrder(int numberOfDishes, int everyDishNumberToEat) {
        LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDishes; i++) {
            linkedList.add(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDishes; i++) {
            int n = linkedList.remove(everyDishNumberToEat+i);
            list.add(n);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Result logic:

```
int step = everyDishNumberToEat - 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (!dishes.isEmpty()) {
        i = (i + step) % dishes.size();
        int n = dishes.remove(i);
        result.add(n);
    }
return result;
```

Comment: This is an instance of the Josephus problem, which is [discussed at length on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

Comment: To treat the list as cyclic list, take the index modulo the current list length.

Comment: How do you handle cases where `everyDishNumberToEat` is a factor of `numberOfDishes`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

- Index to of the element to be removed from the list of dishes should **not** be incremented by `1` at each iteration (*like you're doing in the code you've shared*), but changed according to the given `everyDishNumberToEat`. I.e. we need to walk through the list of dishes repeatedly with a curtain step, and index needs to be changed like that:

```
i = (i + (everyDishNumberToEat - 1)) % dishes.size();

// modulus is need because we need to move the list multiple times,
// until there would be no dishes left (and we don't want
// to exceed the current size of the list)
```

- You need to iterate until the list of dishes **is empty** (*the goal is to eat **all** dishes in curtain order*). A single iteration through the list would not be sufficient because we are skipping the elements. A `while`-loop would be more suitable for that purpose.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static List<Integer> determineDishOrder(int numberOfDishes, int everyDishNumberToEat) {
    List<Integer> dishes = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDishes; i++) {
        dishes.add(i);
    }
    
    int step = everyDishNumberToEat - 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (!dishes.isEmpty()) {
        i = (i + step) % dishes.size();
        int n = dishes.remove(i);
        result.add(n);
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(determineDishOrder(10, 3));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[3, 6, 9, 2, 7, 1, 8, 5, 10, 4]
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for details, it was very helpful!

Comment: @DARASolutions Glad to know. Can you please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74572748/edit) the question and add the **output** your code produces? It's a significant part of the problem. Questions on StackOverflow are supposed to bring value for future readers, therefore it's important to provide a complete and clear problem description, so that someone else can also benefit from your Question. Please, find a minute and do this editing.